# How do you edit an SQL query in Apache Superset?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-superset

I have set up Superset on my Jupiter notebook and it is working i.e. the sample dashboards etc, work. When I try to create a simple table view to just do a `SELECT * from Table` to view the whole table (it is a small table), Superset keeps generating the SQL:

```
SELECT
FROM*
  (SELECT Country,
          Region,
          Users,
          Emails
   FROM `UserStats`
   LIMIT 50000) *AS expr_qry
LIMIT 50000
```

The first `SELECT FROM` and the `AS expr_qry LIMIT 50000` are automatically generated and I cannot get rid of them (i.e. in the Slice view it shows this as the query, but won't let me edit it). Why does it generate its own SQL and where do you change this?
I tried to find workarounds for this but I feel I am missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1):

there is a configuration for 'ROW_LIMIT' in superset/config.py,(default is 50000). if you need remove 'limit cause', try superset/viz.py, query_obj function.